# MySQL Server "No such host is known"

Tags: windows, mysql, host

I am seeing a weird MySQL warning in Windows server event viewer.
The error says : IP Address 'xx.xx.xx.xx' could not be resolved: no such host is known.

Any idea what this means and how critical it is ?

Answer (score 1):

Is MySQL attempting to do reverse resolution of the hostname of connecting clients' IP addresses?  (And do those entries not exist?)

Try adding `skip-name-resolve` to your MySQL configuration.  If you don't need name resolution (no hostnames in the host specification of user accounts) then you may as well have it off.